# Clicking a child component affects parent in an unexpected way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-bubbling, event-capturing

I have two components, Container and Item.

- Container contains Item.
- Item contains a button and a div.

These components have the following behaviors:

- **Container**: When I click **outside** of Container it should disappear, I'm achieving this by using a custom hook that detects clicks outside of components. This works just fine.
- **Item**: When I click in the div which is **inside** Item it should disappear, I'm achieving this by setting a boolean state. This also works but the **problem here is that Container also disappears**.

**Container**

```js
const Container = ({ setDisplay }) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  useClickOutside(containerRef, () => {
    //code to make Container disappear that is not relevant for the issue
    setDisplay(false)
  });
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className='container'>
      <Item />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Item**

```js
const Item = () => {
  const [displayItem, setDisplayItem] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setDisplayItem(true)}>Show Item's content</button>
      {displayItem && (
        <div
          className='item-content'
          onClick={() => setDisplayItem(false)}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**useClickOutside**

```js
const useClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const trigger = e => {
      if (!(ref?.current?.contains(e.target))) handler();
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', trigger);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', trigger);
  }, [handler, ref])
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Note: I have to use that hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the listeners are being attached to the bubbling phase, so the inner ones trigger first.

When the item is shown, and when it's clicked, this runs:

```
<div
  className='item-content'
  onClick={() => setDisplayItem(false)}
>item content</div>
```

As a result, before the event propagates outward, `setDisplayItem(false)` causes this `.item-content` element to be removed from the DOM. See here, how the parent no longer exists afterwards:

```js
const Container = ({ setDisplay }) => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);
  useClickOutside(containerRef, () => {
    //code to make Container disappear that is not relevant for the issue
    console.log('making container disappear');
  });
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className='container'>
      container
      <Item />
    </div>
  );
};
const Item = () => {
  const [displayItem, setDisplayItem] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setDisplayItem(true)}>Show Item's content</button>
      {displayItem && (
        <div
          className='item-content'
          onClick={() => setDisplayItem(false)}
        >item content</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
const useClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const trigger = e => {
      console.log(e.target.parentElement);
      if (!(ref.current.contains(e.target))) handler();
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', trigger);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', trigger);
  }, [handler, ref])
}


ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

You can fix this by changing `useClickOutside` to also check whether the node is connected or not. If it's not connected, the element is no longer in the DOM due to a state change and rerender - so the click that was made wasn't *definitely* outside the `ref.current`, so the handler shouldn't run.

```
const trigger = e => {
  const { current } = ref;
  if (e.target.isConnected && !current.contains(e.target)) {
```

```js
const Container = ({ setDisplay }) => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);
  useClickOutside(containerRef, () => {
    //code to make Container disappear that is not relevant for the issue
    console.log('making container disappear');
  });
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className='container'>
      container
      <Item />
    </div>
  );
};
const Item = () => {
  const [displayItem, setDisplayItem] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setDisplayItem(true)}>Show Item's content</button>
      {displayItem && (
        <div
          className='item-content'
          onClick={() => setDisplayItem(false)}
        >item content</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
const useClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const trigger = e => {
      const { current } = ref;
      if (e.target.isConnected && !current.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log(current.parentElement);
        handler();
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', trigger);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', trigger);
  }, [handler, ref])
}


ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```